# Replace duplicate value with the value from another column on each row where a duplicate is located

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe (Duplicate `ID` 1 and 3):

```
ID    Name    ALT_ID
1     Jack    111
1     James   222
2     Joe     333
3     Jim     444
3     Jen     555
```

How do I replace duplicate `ID` with `ALT_ID` for each occurrence? I would want the final dataframe to look like this:

```
ID    Name    ALT_ID
1     Jack    111
222   James   222
2     Joe     333
3     Jim     444
555   Jen     555
```

This will be a massive dataframe but long running time is not really an issue. Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide, thanks!

I've been using 'pandas' so far so any functions that would help me from that library would be a big bonus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated), a method of your dataframe to locate which values are dupes in your "ID" column. Then use the same rows but take the value in "ALT_ID":

```
>>> df.loc[df["ID"].duplicated(), "ID"] = df.loc[df["ID"].duplicated(), "ALT_ID"]
>>> df
    ID   Name  ALT_ID
0    1   Jack     111
1  222  James     222
2    2    Joe     333
3    3    Jim     444
4  555    Jen     555
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution here. Unfortunately for me I am getting a blank `ID` value when I try to write this dataframe to a CSV file. Is there something obvious that could be tripping me up?

Comment: That does not seem to be related with my answer (if you use the same code). Can you try to find where does the dataframe become empty/None?

Comment: Ahh thank you! You prompted me to just print the dataframe to the console and it turns out I had an extra column pushing everything 1 to the right! Sorted that now and its working perfectly. Appreciate the time taken to send the solution over :)

Answer (score 2):

Without overriding anything in `df`:

```py
df2 = df.assign(ID=df['ID'].where(~df.duplicated(['ID']), df['ALT_ID']))
>>> df2
    ID   Name  ALT_ID
0    1   Jack     111
1  222  James     222
2    2    Joe     333
3    3    Jim     444
4  555    Jen     555
```

Or, in place:

```py
mask = df.duplicated('ID')
df.loc[mask, 'ID'] = df.loc[mask, 'ALT_ID']
```

Comment: Same comment as aaossa's answer... Unfortunately for me I am getting a blank `ID` value when I try to write this dataframe to a CSV file. Is there something obvious that could be tripping me up?

Comment: Could you indicate the result of `df.dtypes`? It could happen if you have a mix of `int` and `str` (shown as `int64` and `object`, respectively).

Comment: Thanks Pierre it turns out I had an extra column pushing everything over 1 to the right :) Thanks a lot of sending over the solution this also worked!